# DB Table update with current data + random number from a range defined in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a php script but I'm kinda stuck and don't know where to begin. Maybe you can give me a few tips.

Here is an example of what the script will do:

I have a database containing two tables: **Users** and **Budgets**.
After the user has logged in he has a menu where he can increase the budget allocated to the  account.

The **Users** table has a field named **AvailableBudget** witch defines how much money the user can spend; While the **Budgets** table contains 3 fields (ID, BudgetName, MinBudget, MaxBudget).

When the user will access the budget menu, a dropdown list will display the BudgetNames from within the **Budgets** table.

Based on the user selection the **AvailableBudget** field (from **Users** table) will update with the following

> $newbudget= mysql_query("UPDATE 'users' SET  'AvailableBudget'=
>   'AvailableBudget')   **+ (Random Number between MinBudget - MaxBudget declared in the Budgets table)**

Now i'm not sure where to start since the **AvailableBudget** field needs to update with the current AvailableBudget+ the random number witch is based on values from another table, and also based on what the user selected from the dropdown menu.
Must specify that the **Budgets** table will contain multiple data:

> > (ID, BudgetName, MinBudget, MaxBudget)
> >
> > 1 -- Budget1 -- 100 -- 1000
> >
> > 2 -- Budget2 -- 1000 -- 10000

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You may need multiple queries. I'm sure there's a way to do this in strict sql, but here is my method.
Note: This is assuming budgets have a unique identifier that assigns them to a user.

```
SELECT u.availablebudget, b.minbudget, b.maxbudget FROM users u
   LEFT JOIN budgets b ON u.id=b.uid

 $newbudget = $oldbudget + rand($minbudget, $maxbudget);


 UPDATE 'users' SET 'AvailableBudget'= 'AvailableBudget'
```

Answer (score 0):

I exactly didn't get your problem, but you can update one table using another in this way.

```
$newbudget= mysql_query("UPDATE 'users' SET 'AvailableBudget'= 'AvailableBudget') + (select ROUND((RAND() * (max-min))+min) from Budget order by rand() limit 1).
```